# Data Caching objects in asp.net 4.5

Tags: caching

How come I can't find the namespace System.Web.Caching.Cache (when I look under references) to do data caching for objects in my asp.net 4.5 web project?

Comment: I simply want to do something like: Cache["object"] = object in .Net

Comment: If not with this namespace, which one do I use and what would the syntax be?